# How to indicate that member fields are @Nonnull by default?

Tags: java, findbugs, jsr305

My question is a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255738/deprecated-annotations-in-findbugs-2-0).

In past versions of FindBugs, it was possible to use `@DefaultAnnotation(Nonnull.class)` or `@DefaultAnnotationForFields(Nonnull.class)` to indicate that all *fields* in a package should be treated as `@Nonnull`. In the current version of FindBugs (2.0), `@DefaultAnnotation` and `@DefaultAnnotationForFields` are deprecated, and we should all use JSR-305 instead. But JSR-305 doesn't seem to cover everything the (now deprecated) FindBugs annotations cover.

The [javadoc](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/DefaultAnnotation.html) does suggest a number of alternatives:

- `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`. This (obviously) only applies to parameters, not to member fields.
- `@CheckReturnValue`, when applied to a type or package. Again, this doesn't apply to member fields.
- `@TypeQualifierDefault`. Maybe this can do what I want, but I don't understand how it works, and I'm unable to find any documentation or examples on its usage or intent, besides some cryptic javadoc. I think it will help me create my own annotations, but can I be sure that all the tools (FindBugs, Eclipse, etc.) will interpret this new annotation correctly (or even at all)?

The [javadoc](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/DefaultAnnotationForFields.html) doesn't provide any hints on how to deal with its deprecation.

So, using the current versions of FindBugs and/or JSR-305, how should I indicate that all member fields in a certain package (or even in a certain class) are supposed to be treated as `@Nonnull`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar question, and found that the following seems to work with findbugs (2.0.1-rc2)

Create a java file with the following annotation definition

```
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FieldsAreNonNullByDefault
{
}
```

similarly, to enforce that all return values from a method are non-null

```
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ReturnTypesAreNonNullByDefault
{
}
```

and then annotate the package as normal.

I used the following for my tests (package-info.java)

```
@javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@com.habit.lib.lang.FieldsAreNonNullByDefault
@com.habit.lib.lang.ReturnTypesAreNonNullByDefault

package com.mypackagename.subpkg;
```

Comment: Ah, so the trick is defining your own annotation... I guess that's more extensible, but I don't see why they can't just make a standard annotation for this case like they did with ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.

Comment: Note that you're using different capitalization for `Nonnull` in your custom annotations than used by those in JSR-305 which may invite confusion.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using IntelliJ IDEA, Spring Boot, Lombok, and Jackson. What do I need to do so they respect package-info.java?